# getting radio button selection in PySide using Python 3.4

Tags: python

The radio buttons are in a submenu off the main menubar.

Cannot get the value of the radio box clicked in PySide this worked perfectly in Tkinter
and also how would one set default radio button checked in PySide?

in PySide: Cannot get value of radio box when changed/selected in pyside. This Works perfectly in tkinter below

```
    os.chdir(user+'database')
    dbfiles=glob.glob('ias*.db')    

    #self.var=('ias'+yr+'.db') used to set default radio button? somehow


    self.ag = QActionGroup(self)
    for self.x in dbfiles: #dbfiles is a "list" of 3 databases 
        dbselect = self.ag.addAction(QAction(self.x, self, checkable=True))#how to set default?
        self.menuDatabases.addAction(dbselect)
    self.ag.triggered.connect(self.displaydb)  #need to trigger something else?

def displaydb(self):
    print(self.x) #need to print something else maybe?
```

In TK; Works perfectly here change radio button and will print database name to textbox

```
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~')+'/Desktop/data/database')
    self.dbfiles=glob.glob('ias*.db')

    self.var=StringVar()
    self.var.set('ias'+str(dte)+'.db')
    for x in self.dbfiles:
        dbfle.add_radiobutton(label=x,variable=self.var, value=x,command=self.sel)

def sel(self):
   selection = "You changed to database: " + str(self.var.get())
   self.b.delete(1.0,END)
   self.b.insert(END,selection)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set one of the actions checked at the start:

```
self.ag.actions()[0].setChecked(true) 
#selects first action, or do this at creation time
```

and change the callback:

```
def sel(self, action):
    print action.text()
```

Comment: self.ag[0].setChecked(true) throws a QActionGroup object is not subscriptable